# Does ElasticSearch in localstack support Data Streams?

Tags: elasticsearch, localstack

I am running localstack with ElasticSearch latest version which is `7.7.0` currently and when create a data stream I am getting and error.

```
 "error" : "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_index_template/my-datastream?pretty] and method [PUT], allowed: [POST]",
```

Here is the curl (mappings are replaced with dotes to keep it simple):

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:4571/_index_template/my-datastream?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "audit-datastream*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "lifecycle": {
          "name": "my-policy"
        },
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
         .....
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "priority": 500,
  "version": 1,
  "data_stream": {}
}
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datastreams were added in 7.9 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/data-streams.html

ps - it's Elasticsearch, not ElasticSearch ;)

Comment: Thanks! Did not find that link with release notes for specific version.